# How to use page.evaluate() from puppeteer to get all network requests?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Is there any way to make `page.evaluate()` wait until there are no more network requests for at least 500ms (like `page.goto()` waits for `networkidle0`)?

For example:

```
await page.evaluate('window.location = "https://example.com"');
// listen to the network requests until there are no requests fired for at least 500 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

`waitUntil` only makes sense in a navigation context. If you mean having `waitUntil` option for `evaluate()` itself the answer is no. However, if you trigger a navigation using `evaluate()` you can use `waitForNavigation()`:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => window.location = "https://example.com")
await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
```